# Overvoltage protection with Zener for this reverse-polarity blocking schematic?

Tags: over-voltage-protection

There is a very nice *reverse-polarity* blocking schematic, discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/608921/reverse-current-blocking-how-do-these-dual-fets-work):

[image]

How shall I replace `SW1`, to immediately (as-soon-as-possible) open when `Vout` is raising above a certain voltage level (like above 5.1V)?

I thought of a Zener diode, to put after `M2`, and some transistor(s): I wish to keep it as simple and as fast as possible.

Current DC Sweep simulation is this:

[image]

My goal is to have it something like this:

[image]

How should I do this? Bipolar? FET? Anything else?

Comment: An open-collector comparator can do this.

Comment: I've used almost  this exact circuit in production  :  https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2019/11/simple-overvoltage-protection-circuit-using-zener-diode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fumkQ5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: simulation]

This solution basically consists of a poor man's comparator (D1, R2, M3) and an open-drain inverter (M4).

M3 turns on approximately when vcmp reaches M3's threshold voltage: 4V for the IRF530.

To set your voltage limit: \$ V_{lim} =V_{Z1}+V_{th3} \$

In this example, \$ V_{Z1} = 1V\$

M4 inverts the output of the comparison for use with the on/off switch (SW1).

Some additional notes:

- Small signal MOSFETs or NPN transistors can be used for M3 and M4 assuming voltage limits are still respected
- The switch is optional
- D1, R2, and M3 can be replaced with the commonly used TL431 and some other parts (https://www.ti.com/product/TL431) for much improved voltage limit precision
- There is reverse leakage current via R2 and D1

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to apply the whole comparator circuit after M1? Applying it before M2 can't cause harm to it? Like when applied 30V reversed: -30V? With -30V, M1 & M2 would cut the circuit, and overvoltage-protection is not needed in this case. However when correct polarity is used, but supply is faulty and we get +30V, overvoltage protection could work perfectly after M1? What's your opinion?

Comment: @Daniel After M1: No. When M1 turns off, there is no more voltage for comparison with the comparator. Trying a simulation of this shows that negative feedback occurs and the circuit turns into a voltage regulator. Damage is possible to the MOSFETs if the forward or reverse voltages exceed the G-S voltage limits of M3 or M4. This can be high for some MOSFETs but might not cover your full range. Some diodes can help this issue.

Comment: What is `VZ1` and `Vth3` in voltage limit calculation?

Comment: @Daniel `VZ1` is the knee voltage of Zener diode D1 and `Vth3` is the threshold voltage of MOSFET M3